# PHP Native Session Issue on Windows IIS

Tags: php, windows, session, iis-7

My current application id developed in zend framework 1.11 but session is being handled using php session handler http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandlerinterface.php

The issues is that when i print $_SESSION in the _initSession() method of /application/Bootstrap.php file then session array does not show correct session data. Here is my source code

```
protected function _initSession() {       
    $handler = new My_Core_SessionHandler_Database();
    session_set_save_handler(
        array($handler, 'open'),
        array($handler, 'close'),
        array($handler, 'read'),
        array($handler, 'write'),
        array($handler, 'destroy'),
        array($handler, 'gc')
     );        
     session_start();
     echo "<pre>";print_r($_SESSION);echo "</pre>";
}
```

When i enter the URL of my application first time in the browser, then $_SESSION become empty array which is OK because session is being written in the `write` method of My_Core_SessionHandler_Databse class into the database and this method is invoked upon completion of request.

But on page refresh read method is invoked first that returs the below session string

```
My_Core_Session|a:1:{s:16:"My_Core_Session";a:4:{s:19:"previous_controller";N;s:15:"previous_action";N;s:18:"current_controller";s:16:"authentification";s:14:"current_action";s:5:"login";}}
```

However the output of $_SESSION variable is

```
Array
(
    [My_Core_Session] => 
)
```

I am not sure why session is not being showing correctly? is it something related to cookies or session issues?